# Trying to make a CSS button that grows on hover, with text remaining the same size

Tags: css

Page with buttons here: http://teamcherry.com.au/jam-games/

The effect I'm trying to achieve with the links on this page is that the button expands when hovered, with the text remaining the same size, and the text staying in the same position on the screen (so the button doesn't appear to 'move' when changing size).

After researching for a while, I've managed to achieve the desired effect using the below css, which changes the padding an margin on hover using css transition:

```
a.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #d11b34;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
        transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

a.btn:hover {
    background-color: #a61529;
    padding: 15px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    margin: -5px;
}
```

This achieves the effect, but the effect is super jittery when animating in Chrome (and possibly other browsers) and the button seems to quiver when hovering.

Is there another way to achieve this precise effect without animation jittering? Ideally in pure CSS but if JS or JQ is required then that's what I'll use.

Comment: Instead of providing a link to you page try posting a demo to http://jsfiddle.net/ instead. That way when your site is fixed there is still a demonstration of what your problem is.

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense. Still new here. Cheers for letting me know.

Comment: You can check this out, it provides a workaround to your issue : http://stackoverflow.com/a/25362700/1811992

Answer (score 1):

Use hardware acceleration and add a bit more time to the animation (you can adjust if needed) and it looks nice. You can also use ease-in-out for a smoother effect. Tested in FF and Chrome

```
a.btn {
display: inline-block;
background-color: #d11b34;
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 20px;
padding: 10px;
padding-right: 20px;
padding-left: 20px;
-webkit-border-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px;
transition: all 0.6s ease;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
-moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
-ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
-o-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I just tried your code, it's an improvement but using Chrome on a Mac I still see the box jittering as it animates, although the text itself stays in place now. Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this by box-shadow

```
a {
    transition: .2s ease;

    &:hover {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 .3rem $color;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use `transition scale` . That is smoother solution for you :)

```
a.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #d11b34;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1,1);
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 250ms;
    -moz-transform: scale(1,1);
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -moz-transition-duration: 250ms;
}

a.btn:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.05,1.07);
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 250ms;
    -moz-transform: scale(1.05,1.07);
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -moz-transition-duration: 250ms;

}
```

Tested in chrome console. Hope it helps :)

Comment: The scales the text as well. The question states that the text size should be unchanged.

Comment: Yes Jon, that's correct. Thanks for taking a look Khaleel, but yeah, I need the text to remain untransformed

Comment: Oh yeah. Try nesting divs instead of anchor and text, and apply transform scale only to parent div not with text containing div.